# "Vote to close" bug

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was trying to vote to close a question<sup>1</sup> as a duplicate and, after I entered the URL of the duplicate question and clicked 'Vote to Close', nothing happened (ie., there was no response *at all*)—despite the fact that I still have 24 votes remaining.

I tried several more times, eventually<sup>2</sup> getting an error in the yellow pop-up box:

```
Question #0 does not exist
```

I tried this two more times to confirm.

Flagging the post worked fine.

1. [How do I connect to a new wifi on the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24410/how-do-i-connect-to-a-new-wifi-on-the-command-line)
2. The only way I can reproduce the error box is to step through selecting all of the other reasons to close the question before reselecting "exact duplicate" and resubmitting the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the original issue was (my best guess is a flaky internet connection at that moment), but either way your repro steps in point 2 indeed were a bug. When you've chosen "exact duplicate" as the close reason, the "Vote to close" button should be disabled until a duplicate question is chosen and confirmed. This wasn't always happening so far, but will be the case after the next build. Thanks!